# "considering either to go"/"thinking of either going"/"thinking whether to go" back to Germany

Tags: sentence-choice

Is there any difference between the following sentences? Are they all acceptable?

> I am considering either to go back to Germany or stay in France.

> I am thinking of either going back to Germany or staying in France.

> I am thinking whether to go back to Germany or stay in France.

Comment: What do you think Alexander? Can you tell us what doubts you might have?

Comment: _Consider_ needs a gerund, not an infinitive. _I am considering either going back to Germany or staying in France._

Answer (score 0):

> I am considering either *to go back to Germany* or *stay in France*.

> I am thinking of either *going back to Germany* or *staying in France*.

> I am thinking whether to *go back to Germany* or *stay in France*.

Overall, we check for parallelism.

For (1) and (2), we use the 'either...or' correlative conjunction pair as markers.

(1) has an infinitive *to go* in the first phrase but not in the second.  There is hence a problem.

(2) is fine.

(3) is fine too; the phrases *go back to Germany* and *stay in France* are parallel.